# Schema compare is too slow

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

We are using the latest version SSDT and TFS extensively. There are around 20 database projects for which we utilize publishing.

There is one database though for which we cannot use the publish and as a result builds. The problem is that this database consist of huge number of schema and database objects. And I mean it. They are getting created dynamically and after some time the "garbage collector" process drops old objects.

Unfortunately the database contains a single schema with a static code, that we cannot move out of this database. In fact there are very few objects in this schema. So correspondent VS database project contains handful of objects

Every time we try either compare or publish changes via SSDT our VS runs out of the space after running for almost hour.

We are not enabling any "DROP ... " advance options. I tried different combinations of options in the profile. Nothing works.

I wonder if there is any way to

1. either include only a set of (or a single) schema
2. or let publishing know to compare objects that are in TFS only and ignore all of the rest objects

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It seems strange that you are version controlling a database that contains dynamically created objects

Comment: NIck. ".... Unfortunately the database contains a single schema with a static code, that we cannot move out of this database....."

Comment: Can you clarify what mean by "huge number" of schema and database objects? Hundreds? Thousands? Some rough stats might help identify if this is unusual behaviour or simply stretching SSDT to its limit. Also, can you clarify if you want to source control all of the schema objects (given many of them are dynamically managed as you mention) or just a subset?